# What is the truth about the lock screen in android?

Tags: android, locking, screen

When your device is powered off and you want to unlock, you click some button and the device is turned on, then you must slide something to unlock.
This view I want to change to my custom view, add some information about battery, add    custom clock or something else. I was looking for information about this, but I didn't find anything. I know, that it it possible to do, because in google play I found a few examples. One of them is [Lock Screen 7](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rout.lock.lockscreen7).

Did you know, how can I modify this view?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-replace-and-customize-android-lock-screen-guide/

You may need root access to make certain changes.

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for. I sow this. I haven't root access in my phone but this application which I show up in first post, working well.